# How do I setup admin routes in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.2

this code (http://bin.cakephp.org/view/172084837) is added to routes.php to connect from "/admin/pages/add" to "/admin/posts/add", but this error is occured: PagesController could not be found.

Answer (score 1):

Enable Admin Area from app/Config/core.php

```
Routing.prefixes = array('admin', 'manager');
```

I hope this will work for you.